# how to reload a page in another in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have made 3 websites

```
http://ice-os.com
http://hannahmontana.sf.net
http://demilovato.sf.net
```

they use an iframe on the main page index.html and load all the pages in this iframe 
what i want to do is if some goes to say http://en.ice-os.com/home.html instead of index.html I want to 
reload this home.html in my index.html in the iframe
how can this be done?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><title>Home</title>






  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


  <style>
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
.myFloatBar{
top:0;
left:0;
width:50px;
position:fixed;
}
<style>

  <style type="text/css">
html {overflow: auto;}
html, body, div, iframe {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; border: none;}
iframe {display: block; width: 100%; border: none; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;}
  </style></head><body style="background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" alink="#ee0000" link="#0000ee" vlink="#551a8b">
<div style="margin-left: 50px; font-family: monospace;"><iframe id="tree" name="tree" src="home.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" height="100%" scrolling="auto" width="100%"></iframe></div>

<div class="myFloatBar"><span style="font-family: monospace;">&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(233, 233, 233); font-family: monospace;">氷Bar</span><img src="http://ice-os.com/images/home.png" alt="Home" title="Home" onclick="document.getElementById('tree').src='home.html';document.title='Home'" style="width: 48px; height: 48px;"><img onclick="document.getElementById('tree').src='downloads.html';document.title='Downloads'" style="width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt="Downloads" title="Downloads" src="http://ice-os.com/images/downloads.png"><img onclick="document.getElementById('tree').src='links.html';document.title='Links'" style="width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt="Links" title="Links" src="http://ice-os.com/images/links.png"><img style="width: 48px; height: 48px;" onclick="document.getElementById('tree').src='projects.html';document.title='Projects'" alt="Projects" title="Projects" src="http://ice-os.com/images/projects.png"><img style="width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt="Revision Control" title="Revision Control" src="http://ice-os.com/images/revisioncontrol.png"><img style="width: 48px; height: 48px;" onclick="document.getElementById('tree').src='contact.html';document.title='Contact'" alt="Contact" title="Contact" src="http://ice-os.com/images/contact.png"><img onclick="document.getElementById('tree').src='about.html';document.title='About'" style="width: 48px; height: 48px;" alt="About" title="About" src="http://ice-os.com/images/about.png"></div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: It would be better for everyone (you, the user, the search engines), if you recreate your pages without the frames. This can be done with CSS.

Comment: @HerrSerker how would this be done in css then?

Comment: Learn about fixed positioning http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/fC2Zf/

Comment: @HerrSerker Pretty nice I might use some of this later. BTW I already use css for my side bar i just load the content in an iframe so onley one page has the bar on it. also that tool you gave a link to is super cool.

Comment: I accept the motivation, that you don't want the navigation to be repeated on every page, but it is regarded as bad style amongst leading web professionalists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, it's been a while, but I've seen this done with Javascripts that force users into framesets. I remember it from back in the late 90s, but I think it's kind of fallen out of favor since users have generally hated frames. (Usually this was for navigation on sites that, for whatever reason at the time, either didn't support server-side includes or perhaps the developer didn't understand includes...)

You can probably Google "javascript open page in frameset" and find a sample.

Comment: OK I got this it worked    <script>

if (parent.location.href == self.location.href){
    window.location.href = 'index.html'
}

</script>

Comment: but the problem with this code is it does not change the contains of the iframe to the page that called it

Comment: I've seen this done in framesets - basically the content detects whether or not it's loaded in the frame through a javascript, and then redirects to the proper frameset...I'll try to dig you up a sample, but it's been a while...

Comment: Does this point you in the right direction? http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/openinframeset1.html

Comment: Yeah it does I found this yesterday. Thanks